# Xamarin Forms: Prism -- Issue with using unity IoC?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, inversion-of-control, prism

In my xamarin forms app using Prism MVVM Framework, How should I use IoC containers?
There are no

```
Container.Resolve<Interface,Implentation>
```

I think we need to resolve the IoC and initialize in app.xaml.cs. But I am not able to find proper way to do it.
Can anyone help me out ?

**UPDATE:**

PAGE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
        xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms" 
        prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True" 
        x:Class="CoC.Core.Views.MenuPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
            <ListView x:Name="info" 
            SeparatorVisibility="None"
            SeparatorColor="Transparent"
            HasUnevenRows="false"
            RowHeight="50" BackgroundColor="#485366" > 
        <ListView.ItemTemplate> 
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <!--<ImageCell Text="{Binding Title}" ImageSource="{Binding IconSource}" /> -->
                        <ViewCell>
                            <!--<Label Text="{Binding Title}" />-->
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

ViewModel:

```
using Prism.Commands;
using Prism.Mvvm;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Prism.Navigation;

namespace CoC.Core.ViewModels
{
    public class MenuPageViewModel : BindableBase , INavigationAware
    {
        IMenuList _menuList;
        public ObservableCollection<MenuItem> ConductList { get; set; }

        public void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationParameters parameters)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }  

        public MenuPageViewModel(IMenuList MenuList)
        {
            _menuList = MenuList;
            ConductList = _menuList.GetMenuList();
        }

    }
}
```

APP:

```
using Prism.Unity;
using CoC.Core.Views;

namespace CoC.Core
{
    public partial class App : PrismApplication
    {
        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //NavigationService.NavigateAsync("MainPage?title=Hello%20from%20Xamarin.Forms");
            NavigationService.NavigateAsync("MenuPage");
        }

        protected override void RegisterTypes()
        {
            Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<MainPage>();
            Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<RootPage>();
            Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<MenuPage>();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code, I am getting error in Main.cs of IOS pro
Error:
Foundation.MonoTouchException
NSInternalLnconistencyException Reason: Application window are expected to have a root view controller at the end of the application.

Comment: Install Visual Studio Extension for Prism template pack and using it create solution

Comment: I did. It don't resolve the issue

Comment: Using Container to register your IMenuList interface to a class

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921149.aspx

Comment: Those are for prism in wpf i think. Don't have similar API's in Prism MVVM framework for Xamarin.

Comment: Where are you calling RegisterTypes method from? Not familiar with Prism so perhaps it gets called by the library, so just checking.

Comment: I am trying to call them from startup app page  (App.xaml.cs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is an extension method in Unity. You need to add the `using Microsoft.Practices.Unity` namespace to your code file. The you can register your services using `Container.Register<IService,MyService>()`.

Comment: I added the namespace. Unity container doesn't have Register, it had RegisterType function. So, I added  `container.RegisterType<IMenu, Menu>();` but i am still getting the same error.

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong. You may have an issue somewhere else in your code.